# Php multiple file download as zip and rename all files name under zip

Tags: php

I need to download all files form url and download as a zip. Every thing is working but i am not able to rename the file names under zip. I am using below code

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
{ 
$error = "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}else{
foreach ($_POST as $file) {
foreach($file as $res){
$download_file = file_get_contents($res);
$zip->addFromString(basename($res), $download_file);
}
}
$zip->close();
}
```

can anyone please help me how can i rename the files?

Comment: What does "not able renane the file names" mean?

Comment: your `$_POST as $file` is nonsense written in this way, as you are iterating over all POST fields (file inputs and other input types). for file inputs the POST array item is a sub-array, which you didn't mentionnend : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you use the line

```
$zip->addFromString(basename($res), $download_file);
```

...that means: add the downloaded file under it's name to the archive. If you want to change the file name that should occur in the archive, you should start looking here